# How to find out unused items

Tags: cms

The CMS has many duplicate/redundant items and I would like to delete them.
When I select an item (say *Item-A*) and check `Navigate > Links`, there are no items that refer *Item-A*.

But, somewhere else, *Item A* is being referred in the rendering datasource field like this:
`query:$site/Data/Banners`

When items are not referenced directly and instead using a query, then even when I delete *Item-A*, it does not show any alert that it is being used.

In such scenario, is there a way to find out unused items.

Using Sitecore 10.1.3 with SXA.

Comment: Rebuild your link database, then you can run the PowerShell command to find reference items.

Answer (score 1):

This code helps to find the related item.

```
var unusedItems = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItems().Where(item =>
    !Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item).Any());
```

and if you are using SPE, below code will help

```
# Get all items in the content tree
$allItems = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Language *

# Get the reference map
$refMap = Get-ItemReferrerMap -Item $allItems

# Find items not referenced by any other item
$unusedItems = $allItems | Where-Object { -not $refMap.ContainsKey($_.ID) }

# Output the unused items
$unusedItems | Format-Table -Property Name, ItemPath
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a readymade solution available for this. These tokens `$site` is evaluated at runtime and hence you do not see it in references.

Since you already have content ready, you can create a handler when item is deleted `item:deleting` event and look for such cases under content node. This would be a complex code considering multiple scenarios like checking presentation and evaluating those tokens.

```
     public class OnItemDeletingValidator
       {
        public void OnItemDeleting(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
         Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
         // Your logic to iterate through content items and find if this item is used under Page presentation
        }
       }
```

And register this event using a config patch file.

Here is an article with details - https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2020/01/03/sitecore-use-itemdeleting-event-to-avoid-deletion-of-items/

Hope this helps !